# stage.nativeWindow.activate() in AS3 doesn't bring minimized apps to front

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an app (App1) that gets displayed in front of any other apps when a button in another app (App2) is clicked (the two apps are connected via sockets).

It works fine if App1 was maximized or restored down to start with, but if it was minimized, it will be brought forward, but still kept behind App2.

I can half get around it by first of all maximizing the App1, then bringing it forward, but that's not ideal, as the user may have had App1 restored down before minimizing it, but now after bringing it forward, it's maximized instead of restored down.

Anyone know how to get this to work?

I've tried a bunch of permutations of

```
stage.nativeWindow.activate()
stage.nativeWindow.alwaysInFront=true;
stage.nativeWindow.alwaysInFront=false;
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activate();
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activate(NativeApplication.nativeApplication‌​.openedWindows[0]);
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to test it right now, but try the method orderToFront:

```
stage.nativeWindow.orderToFront();
```

**Note**: If a window is hidden (visible is false) or minimized, then calling the display order methods has no effect. There is a **maximize** method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Oh duh. I had a command I was sending to App2 when I wanted to bring it to the front. Problem was, I was also sending it when I was bringing App1 to the front. So in the end, stage.nativeWindow.activate() did the job just fine.